# Wordpress or Customize back end?

Tags: wordpress, backend

Hello guys im trying to create a student portal for my thesis i want to know what'
s the best backend, Wordpress or create your own back end? Im starting from the scratch and im new to html and css. Please can someone give me suggestions or ideas? Thanks guys.

Comment: This is opinion-based, but if the thesis isn't specifically about building your own back end then I don't understand why you would want to do all that work instead of using a ready made solution.

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress is designed for organizing content, like blogs, static content or shops, not handling users registration, interactivity, or walled-off content. It might be possible to accomplish this with Wordpress, but it won't be fast, elegant or cheap. I would suggest looking at a custom HTML solution with a mix of libraries to handle your requirements.